# Trying to update to Kodi 17.3... but..?

Tags: kodi

I was trying to following the directions from Kodi to clear out kodi-bin and kodi-data so that I could update Kodi 17.1 to 17.3.  After doing so and trying to install Kodi it get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (>= 2:17.3+git20170525.0741-final-0xenial) but 17.1+hk2-odroidc2ubuntu2 is to be installed
        Depends: libshairplay0 but it is not installable
        Recommends: i965-va-driver but it is not installable or
                    libva-intel-vaapi-driver but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I am really not sure how to proceed and and really not sure where the problem really is.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have Kodi's PPA?

Comment: Latest Kodi release is 17.4 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

So new to Linux (it's scary) but I had the same issue, tried the following and it worked for me...

For Xenial go to:

https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcepub/7832292/+listing-archive-extra

scroll to the bottom of the page, download both the 'kodi' & 'kodi-bin' .deb packages and install both using:

```
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Hope it helps...

[1]
https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by removing and installing the kodi packages.
The kodi database was in my case still filled, but I  would recommend a backup of the kodi database.

1. Get your installed kodi packages

   ```
   sudo apt list --installed | grep kodi
   ```
2. Remove kodi packages found in 1

   ```
   sudo apt remove kodi kodi-bin ...
   ```
3. Install kodi again

   ```
   sudo apt install kodi
   ```